# Download runtime file after login using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

I'am new in web scraping, and I want to download runtime csv file (The button has no URL, it uses JS function) after login, I have tried using https://curl.trillworks.com/# ,and it works fine, but it uses a dynamic cookies.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    ...,
}

headers = {
    ...
}

data = {
    ...
}

s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(posturl, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, verify=False)
```

Cookies is dynamic, so every time I want to download files, I have to get the new cookies, so I'have tried something different using the same script

```
payload = {
  'login': 'login',
  'username': 'My_name',
  'password': 'My_password',
}

logurl = "http:..."
posturl = 'http:...'

s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(logurl, headers=headers, data=data)
# response = s.post(posturl, data=payload,auth=(my_name, my_password)) #This too gives me the wrong output
```

But this doesn't give me the right output, it gives me the first page text/html, the response headers gives me two different content type

```
print response.headers['Content-Type']
```

for the right output is `'text/csv;charset=UTF-8'` but it gives me `'text/html;charset=UTF-8'`, and the `status_code for both is 200`,
for information the posturl for CSV file is the same with html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep searching, I found :
There are completely different tools for web scraping :

1.`request` or `urllib` : widely used tools, it gives us the possibility to make post and get request, and login, create persistent cookies using `Session()` ..., there are a great tools we can use `curl` visit https://curl.trillworks.com/, but that doesn't enough for complicated extracting data.

1. `Beautifullsoup` or `lxml` : Use for `HTML Parser`, navigate in source html, something like regular expression to extract desired element form HTML page `get Title`, find the `div with id=12345`, these tools can't understand the JS button, and can't make an action like `post` or `get` or `click button` or `submit` in form, its just way how to read data from request.
2. `Mechnize` or `robobrowser` or `MechnicalSoup` : Great tools for web browsing and cookies handling, browser history, we can consider these tools as a mix of `request` and `BeautifullSoup`, so we can make `get` and `post` and `submit in form` and navigate in page html content easily like `BeautifullSoup`, these technologies are not a real browser, so its cannot excute and understand JS, and send asynchronous request, or move the scrollbar, or exporting selected data form table ... so these tools not enough to make complicated requests.
3. `Selenium` : is a powerful tools and a real browser, we can get data as we want, we can make `get` and `post` and `search`, `submit`, `selecting`, `move scroolbar`, it used just like we use any navigator, using `Selemenium` nothing is impossible, we can use a real browser with GUI or we can use `option = 'headless'` for server environment.

Blow I explain how we can `submit` in a form and click `JS button` in `server environment` step by step.

A. Install webdriver for server environment :
Open a terminal :

```
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
sudo pip install selenium
```

If you want to use a webdriver for GUI interface download from   https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

B. Example in Python 2.7, it works too for Python 3, just edit print line

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
# define downlaoded directory
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
   "download.default_directory": "/tmp/",
   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    })

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)  # see edit for recent code change.


USERNAME = 'mail'
PASSWORD = 'password'

browser.get('http://www.example.com')
print browser.title

user_input = browser.find_element_by_id('mail_input')
user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)

pass_input = browser.find_element_by_id('pass_input')
pass_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)


login_button = browser.find_element_by_id("btn_123")
login_button.click()

csv_button = browser.find_element_by_id("btn45875465")
csv_button.click()

browser.close() # to close current page or you can use too `browser.quit()` to destroy the hole of webdriver instance

# Check if the file was downloaded completely and seccessfully
file_path = '/tmp/file_name'

while not os.path.exists(file_path):
    time.sleep(1)

if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    print 'The file was downloaded completely and seccessfully'
```